# Verify PEM-Certificate in Bash with error but return code OK

Tags: openssl, certificate, pem, verify

I want to verify whether a certificate is issued by a sub CA or not. I use the following command:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile "/usr/share/jenkins/sub-ca.crt" cert.crt
```

cert.crt is in this case a self-signed certificate, so it is not issued by the sub-ca.crt. sub-ca.crt is a certificate issued by our root-ca.
When I run the command, it shows the correct error:

```
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
```

But under this line 
    OK
is displayed and when I check the return code with $? I get 0 as return code. 
Why is the command returning OK when there is an error occured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `verify` command attempts to build up a chain of certificates, validates that the chain is complete, checks the purpose, check trust settings, checks validity of the whole chain (e.g. against the time etc), etc.

As `verify` is a diagnostic tool it's return code doesn't mean that a certificate successfully verified, it means that the command successfully ran to completion without any fatal errors. Certain classes of errors are treated as non-fatal, such as: self-signed cert, certificate expiry, errors processing certificate extensions etc. Non fatal errors will still be displayed but will not affect the final "OK" outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to check the error-code of this command? I have to know whether it was issued by the CA or not and a self-signed certificate is not acceptable for this purpose.

Comment: I don't think you can do that from the command line (at least not without scraping the text output). You would have to use libcrypto APIs directly to do this.

Answer (score 0):

error 18 which is returned by OpenSSL command in this case indicates that it is a self signed certificate is found at depth 0 and the self signed certificate was not present in it's internal store (or in the case of this command, it is not given along with the -CAfile option).

Generally, OpenSSL tries to form a chain of certificates and it's issuers based on the certificate or certificate chain presented for verification and the certificates given as a part of -CAfile or -CAPath options.

It expects that the self-signed certificate in the chain (i.e. top most certificate of the chain), should be also be presented as a part of -CAfile or -CAPath options, i.e. they are trusted by the verifier.

In the question, this is not the case and hence the error.

Comment: I'm not sure the page you cite is correct when it says *"Since OpenSSL can't verify any of the signers of the [self-signed] certificate, it can't verify the certificate.... Once you get someone on the signing chain trusted [you will get Verify OK(0)]"*. OpenSSL follows RFC 5280 and RFC 4158. The RFCs allow self-signed end-entity certifcates, so there is no reason to reject one that is trusted. If a trusted one (`-CApath` or `-CAfile`) is being rejected, then its a bug in OpenSSL.

Comment: @jww, I am not very clear with your comment. The point here is that there is a self-signed certificate presented for verification and that certificate is also not present in the trusted repository i.e. not presented with -CAfile option. So, it fails. Additional info is that this self-signed certificate is at depth 0. I'll try to rephrase my answer.